# How to make a executable file of JavaFX 2.0 project?

Tags: javafx-2, executable-jar

I want to make a executable file of my project which I made in JavaFX 2.0. Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: Hope this helps https://blogs.oracle.com/talkingjavadeployment/entry/native_packaging_for_javafx

Comment: [another 'solution link'](http://www.javaworld.com/javaworld/jw-05-2012/120529-jtip-deploying-javafx.html) from a link-only answer, below

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The JavaFX team implemented support for this in the tools bundled with the JavaFX 2.2 SDK (included in Java7 from update 6).  The JavaFX packaging toolset for packaging executables is documented in [self-contained application](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm) section of the JavaFX deployment guide.

See [RT-19446](http://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-19446) "Add ability to co-bundle Java + JavaFX + App into a single native executable" for more information (anybody can sign up to view the jira).

3rd party tools such as the [JavaFX maven plugin](https://github.com/zonski/javafx-maven-plugin) or the [JavaFX gradle plugin](https://bintray.com/shemnon/javafx-gradle/gradle-javafx-plugin#read), streamline integration of building native JavaFX executables using common build systems.

The JavaFX packaging tools can also be used to natively package any Java application, not just JavaFX applications.  For example, a Swing application, as demonstrated by this [shell script for packaging a Swing application using JavaFX on OS X](https://gist.github.com/jewelsea/5018976).

If you want to do the packaging for the 2.0 or 2.1 versions of JavaFX (not JavaFX 2.2+), then you should review [Packaging JavaFX Applications as Native Installers](http://fxexperience.com/2012/03/packaging-javafx-applications-as-native/).

Comment: I have created two javafx exes for two different apps , but while installing both of them are getting installed in the same directory(which ever installing first in its directory) , so that I cannot open the application .. How can I solve this ?

Comment: @Wolverine please ask new questions as new questions.

Comment: Sorry I dont have permission , it is blocked :(

Answer (score 4):

Javafx 2+ can now easily be packaged as a native exe (with an added payload, which the current JRE), the up to date (as in the end of 2012) article is here: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/deployment/self-contained-packaging.htm

Out of curiosity I created an executable on Windows (copy-pasting the netbeans build code into netbeans' build.xml) from the canvas and the hello world examples: the app is around 20k, the executable/launcher is around 80k and the added runtime is 138mb.

By the way if you have an older netbeans install (installed with a pre 1.7jdk) you may have to update it or edit its netbeans.conf fixing the "netbeans_jdkhome" path, otherwise the bundled executable's packaging may fail.

Answer (score 3):

There are several tools to generate a customized exe launcher for your Java application.

I have good experience with Winrun4J: http://winrun4j.sourceforge.net/

but you will always need an installed Java/JavaFX Runtime even if you have an .exe that contains all your code.

Comment: The point with jewelsea's mentioned JavaFX 2.2 native packaging is that you wouldn't need to rely on a Java Runtime on the system. It also is embedded with the exe/dmg/rpm.